# Tag descriptions

Tags: discussion, tags

I've begun working on filling in some of the tag descriptions.

Can I get some feedback on these tags, (please feel free to improve them as you see fit)

- [Techniques](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/tags/techniques/info)
- [Barleywine](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/tags/barleywine/info)

---

Specifically for the barleywine tag I'm interested in people's opinions on style tags.

- Should we include the entire BJCP style guideline, or a portion of it in the "Full tag wiki" portion of the description?
- How do we handle the fact that the BJCP includes both American and English Barleywine's?

  - Do we have a "Barleywine" tag and also "Barleywine - English" and "Barleywine - American"

Comment: they look good to me, but I'm hardly a subject matter expert. Bear in mind that *guidance on when to use the tag is key in the excerpt*, and I'd assume anyone reading is (unlike me) at least roughly familiar with any general homebrewing concepts, so they don't need to be explained so much as very briefly summarized.

Comment: seems that techniques is pretty broad, and this may be a good thing, as long as specific technique tags are ok.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing how there are more unused tags or duplicate conceptual tags then not, I think a single Barleywine tag covers it just fine.